# Get Iframe to fill to bottom of page

Tags: html, css, iframe

This seems like it should be a simple question but i cannot seem to find a solution anywhere.

On the website i am making i have a navigation bar at the top of the page that is 43px in height and in an attempt to not have to edit it for each individual page that i make what i did is put an iframe below it at 100% width with the navigation buttons targeting the source of my iframe.

Now where i run into an issue is that i want the iframe to extend from the bottom of the navigation bar to the bottom of the page so that you cannot tell that it was iframed in but if i set the height to 100% it is set to the height of the entire page and adds a 2nd scrollbar to compensate for the extra 43px at the bottom, so how can i fit the iframe to just the remaining space below the nav bar ?

I have tried setting different % but that does not work for different res monitors. And i need this to work cross browser (in IE, Chrome, Safari, and Mozilla, preferably in Opera also but that's not a necessity).

Sorry its a little wordy, can anyone help?

Comment: Congratulations, you win the award for the longest run-on sentence.

Comment: yes, I know lol. I was in a bit of a hurry to finish it because I had other things to do. thank you Zulkhaery Basrul for editing it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple. All you need do is subtract the height of your navigation from the current viewport height and set that as your iframe's height. Use this Javascript method:

```
function ResizeIFrame() {
    var nNavigationHeight = 43; // Assuming the 43px you stated above
    var nViewHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
    var nIframeHeight = nViewHeight - nNavigationHeight;
    document.getElementById("YourIFrameID").style.height = nIframeHeight + "px";
}
```

You'll need to set your body and html to 100% height for this to work.

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

I should mention that this is a somewhat dubious way of achieving what you want to do, but it's a solution true to the letter of your question. I'd recommend you look into using Jquery rather than vanilla Javascript as cross-browser headaches will be minimised (I've tested this code in my current installations of IE 7 & 8, FF, Chrome, and Safari without issue, but your mileage may vary). If you decide to go that route, it would be better to take advantage of their excellent and simple AJAX functionality using a div and dispense with the iframe entirely.

Comment: Thank You but I couldnt get it to work, how should I apply it to my page? just in the head and input the iframe id, or is there something i should apply to the Iframe itself? sorry i'm not too script savy... If it makes a difference this is my page http://astoriaband.webs.com/index.html

Comment: Your page is fine, but you don't ever call the resizing method. The simplest way is to modify your body tag to <body onload="ResizeIFrame();"> which will call the method once the page has finishing loading all its content. Be aware that this includes anything loaded in the iframe.

Comment: Even after calling the function it didn't change, I guess i'll just try it the long way and edit every individual page, thank you for trying though.

Comment: Apologies, I omitted the bit about setting the html tag's height. I've updated my answer and you can find a complete version of the code here: http://demo.sixthcircle.co.za/StackOverflow/ResizeIframeDemo.htm

Comment: Thank You, that worked, although yesterday after having no luck with your code I experimented with CSS for a couple hours and found an alternate method using just css and an extra div. if you're interested here it is: `<div style="position:absolute; top: 43px; bottom: 0px; min-width:970px; width:100%;">
<iframe class="contentiframe" id="cntframe" style=" min-width:970px; width:100%; height:100%;"  frameborder="0" src="home.htm"  ></iframe>
</div>` and set the body to `body
{
        height:100%;
        min-width:950px;
}` as you can see I wrapped the Iframe in a div and set

Comment: The positioning to absolute and then 43px from the top (for my situation) and then 0px from the bottom and 100% wide, then just set the Iframe to 100% height and width. the min-width is to compensate for if the page is zoomed in or the window is resized it wont create a double horizontal scrollbar. this code seems to work better because it automatically resizes the frame when the window is resized and it seems to be more universal since it is only using exrtra css. But again, thank you anyway.